sigmake.exe: too many leaves (12133)
I'm trying to create a FLIRT Signature file from my database pattern (input.pat), but when I run sigmake.exe, i get this output:
C:\Users\Belium\Documents\sig>C:\Users\Belium\Documents\sig\sigmake.exe -n"NET 8.0 NATIVE AOT SIG" C:\Users\Belium\Documents\sig\input.pat output.sig: too many leaves (12133)
Is there any way to disable the limit?
I tried researching, but nobody even asked this question
